# Rich textbox limit number of rows and columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I have textbox or richTextBox in my C# WinForm.

I need to limit the text to 10 characters and five lines.

Like this:

```
----- 10 ----
1234567890  |
1234567890  |
1234567890  5
1234567890  |
1234567890  |
```

And if I paste any text - If the last word is cut, the whole word will be dropped to the next line.

For example:

```
my name Ne
lson
```

Will be like this:

```
my name
Nelson
```

Comment: Well you know what you want and have a draft specification, but I don't see any code to comment on.  You should know by now that this site is not a code writing service.

Comment: SO veteran asking non [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) questions? Please add some code here.

Comment: @Sunil Doesn't look like a 'veteran'. Check the profile. It's someone harvesting lots of rep by asking tons of small code-less questions like this that get dozens of answers. This user hasn't produced a single useful answer on the site. Just loads of questions.